# Setting seed for tensorflow does not work to get reproducible results

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory, random-seed

I run a sequential model in Google Colab. I have tried all suggestions I could find about setting seed so I can get reproducible results but nothing works. train and validation accuracy differ every time, as well as the train and validation losses.

More info about my project:

- Tensorflow version: 2.9.2
- I have paid for the ColabPro version if this matters.

Since I am preprocessing text data I do the following:

```
# Pad tokens (X var)   
tokens = data_sent['word_idx'].tolist()

maxlen = config.MAX_LEN #max([len(s) for s in tokens])

pad_tokens = pad_sequences(tokens, maxlen=maxlen, dtype='int32', padding='post')
```

This is the function I use to split my data:

```
def data_split(features, labels, train_frac, random_state=config.SEED):
  assert train_frac >= 0 and train_frac <= 1, "Invalid training set fraction"

  X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(
      features, labels, train_size=train_frac, random_state=random_state)

  print(
    'train_tokens length:', len(X_train),
    '\ntest_tokens length:', len(X_test),
    '\ntrain_tags:', len(Y_train),
    '\ntest_tags:', len(Y_test),
    )

  return X_train, X_test,  Y_train, Y_test
```

Model:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=config.MAX_TOKENS, output_dim=config.EMBEDDING_DIM, input_length=config.MAX_LEN, mask_zero=True),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=config.EMBEDDING_DIM, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True, dropout=0.2, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.L2(l2_regularizer_start), kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=config.SEED))),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=config.EMBEDDING_DIM, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True, dropout=0.2, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.L2(l2_regularizer_start), kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=config.SEED))),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=config.EMBEDDING_DIM, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True, dropout=0.2, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.L2(l2_regularizer_start), kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=config.SEED))),
    tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_tags, activation='softmax', kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=config.SEED))),
])
```

What I have tried:
1.Set seed for the initializer in each layer:

```
kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=config.SEED)
```

2.At the beginning of the code v0

```
np.random.seed(config.SEED)
random.seed(config.SEED)
tf.random.set_seed(config.SEED)
```

3.At the beginning of the code v1

```
random.seed(SEED)
np.random.seed(SEED)
tf.random.set_seed(SEED)
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED']=str(SEED)
os.environ['TF_DETERMINISTIC_OPS'] = '1'
```

4.At the beginning of the code v2

```
tf.keras.utils.set_random_seed(config.SEED)
tf.config.experimental.enable_op_determinism()
```

5.At the beginning of the code v3

```
def set_seeds(seed=config.SEED):
    os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = str(seed)
    random.seed(seed)
    tf.random.set_seed(seed)
    np.random.seed(seed)

def set_global_determinism(seed=config.SEED):
    set_seeds(seed=seed)

    os.environ['TF_DETERMINISTIC_OPS'] = '1'
    os.environ['TF_CUDNN_DETERMINISTIC'] = '1'
    
    tf.config.threading.set_inter_op_parallelism_threads(1)
    tf.config.threading.set_intra_op_parallelism_threads(1)

# Call the above function with seed value
set_global_determinism(seed=config.SEED)
```

### Update:

If I run the notebook multiple times without restarting the runtime I get the same results.

If I restart the Colab Runtime the results (accuracy and loss) are always different despite the random seed being set and the same each time.

#### Update 1

Using `!nvidia-smi` shows that each time I restart a session in Colab the GPU I am attached to is changing.

So, it appears the Colab creates the issue but I cannot figure out how to fix it.

Comment: "but nothing works" is a bit vague, we would appreciate if you could add a minimal example. Also, keep in mind that other things than random number generators might make your results not exactly reproducible: are you sure you are feeding your data in a consistent way across your runs for example?

Comment: I added a bit more information. I hope it is helpful

Comment: Besides setting all all appropriate random seeds, you could try working with `tensorflow-determinism`. According to https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/help-i-can-set-seed-on-google-colab-tf-keras/1912, the non-deterministic behavior: "[...] is likely because of the non-deterministic CUDA kernels being fired at the backend." Since you are using `Tensorflow 2.9.2`, you should be able to use the feature: `tf.config.experimental.enable_op_determinism()`. Check out the docs for more information:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/experimental/enable_op_determinism

Comment: Note that you can also call `tf.keras.utils.set_random_seed`  to set the Python seed, the NumPy seed, and the TensorFlow seed.

Comment: `tensorflow-determinism` does not work with this version of `tensorflow`. The `enable_op_determinism` I have tried but as long as I restart the runtime results change. I suppose the GPU that my notebook uses is changing or something like this.

Comment: If you are using colab, why not upgrade your tf version then ? And it is very possible that you are assigned different GPUs everytime you log on colab

Comment: Yes, I found out how to see what the GPU is and it is different every time: `!nvidia-smi`

Comment: I do not know of an option to choose a specific GPU on colab. You should maybe try contacting them. But then again, you should ask yourself if accuracy and loss results lying in the near vicinity are acceptable for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

##### TensorFlow v2.11.0

I was having trouble with reproducibility in a tensorflow project that I was working on in a local machine. As @AloneTogether pointed out in the comments above, `tf.keras.utils.set_random_seed` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

From the question, you can use the random generator.

Sample: Random uniform values. Expecting no sequencing output from determining input, accuracy but varies and none determining with gardients.

```
for image in list_file:
    
        g = tf.random.Generator.from_seed(1234)
        g.reset_from_seed( 1235 + icount )
        temp = tf.random.uniform( shape=(4, 1), minval=0, maxval=6, dtype=tf.dtypes.int64,seed=1235 + icount,name="random" )
        arg = tf.math.argmax( temp ).numpy()[0]
        result = temp[arg].numpy()[0]
        icount = icount + 1
```

Output:

```
3
4
3
3
4
3
5
4
5
4
```